# Akka application hang

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

We use akka to stress test one of our systems by sending JMS messages in parallel to our system entry points.
At a very high level, there is a Boss actor and a number of Worker actors that do the job.
When Boss actor is created in its constructor it also creates the Worker actors and puts them in a map:

```
workers = endPoints.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> newWorker(e, ...)));
```

Then when the Boss receives the `StartTesting` message it just iterates to the list of its workers and send a `PerformWork` message to each one. Upon receiving the `PerformWork` message each worker goes to the database get the messages to send out, and start sending them to its associated end point. Nothing out of the ordinary here:

```
logger.info("Number of worker actors: " + workers.values().size());
PerformWork performWork = new PerformWork();
workers.values().forEach(w -> {
    logger.info("Sending PerformWork message to " + w);
    w.tell(performWork, getSelf());
});
```

When running we can see in the logs the following:

```
... Number of worker actors: 43
... Sending a PerformWork message to Actor[akka://.../WORKER-1
... Sending a PerformWork message to Actor[akka://.../WORKER-2
.
... WORKER-1: received message of type PerformWork
... Sending a PerformWork message to Actor[akka://.../WORKER-30
.
```

The number of `Sending a PerformWork` log entries are never equals with the number of workers (43 in this case). Usually between 20 and 30 but not necessarily always the same. The number of `WORKER-x received message of PerformWork` entries are usually smaller than the messages sent. The worker actors that actually received the `PerformWork` message perform what they are supposed to do without any problem.

However we never seen the rest of the `Sending ...` or `Received ...` messages in the logs for the rest of the workers, and obviously those end points associated with them never receive any message.

So my questions would be:

1. What I am doing wrong? Maybe my approach is too naive. I am not very experienced with akka, never used it beyond building testing tools.
2. What will cause the sending PerformMessage loop above to never complete.
3. What will cause the delivery of PerformMessage above to fail.

All this processing is happening inside the same JVM. I am open to any other suggestion that will help me understand what is going on and address the issue.

The testing tool is written in Java. I added the Scala tag thinking that Scala developers would be more familiar with akka, given Actor framework is part of the language.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I worked out what was causing the issue, and I was able to fix it, however I still don't have an explanation about why was happening and it would be good to have an understanding.

So before the fix the Worker code looked like below:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Object message) throws InterruptedException {
    if (message instanceof PerformWork) {
        // here is the code using jdbcTemplate to get messages 
        // from database and send them to the system end point

        getSender().tell(new WorkDone(), getSelf());
    } else {
        logger.info("Not prepared to handle message of type " + message.getClass());
        unhandled(message);
    }
}
```

And I changed it to start sending messages with a delay of two seconds:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Object message) throws InterruptedException {
    if (message instanceof PerformWork) {
        new Timer().schedule(
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        proceedWithSendingMessages();
                    }
                },
                2000
        );
    } else {
        logger.info("Not prepared to handle message of type " + message.getClass());
        unhandled(message);
    }
}

private void proceedWithSendingMessages() {
    // here is the code using jdbcTemplate to get messages
    // from database and send them to the system end point
    getSender().tell(new WorkDone(), getSelf());
}
```

After the above change everything started working but the question I have is why the issue existed in the first place. It seems to me that what I experienced is against the asynchronous processing concept.

Again thank you in advance for your inputs.

**UPDATE 2**
In a normal run each worker runs for 24 hours. Remember it is a stress/load test so no `WorkDone` message is sent back to the Boss in less than this time. My akka application got hung after less than one second after starting. As I said all the workers that received the `PerformWork` were running normally and kept sending messages for 24 hours.

When receiving a `WorkDone` message the Boss verify if all Workers are done and if so it shuts down akka. I am attaching the code here as it was requested but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem.

```
} else if (message instanceof WorkDone) {
    // completed below is a set
    completed.add(((WorkDone) message).getSystem())
    if (completed.size() == workers.size()) {
        shutDownAkka();
    }
}
```

I realized that was the Worker starting the work immediately after receiving a `PerformWork` message causing my issue by changing the database in such a way that it will be nothing to send so by querying an empty database made everything to work OK but finished straight away.

I suspected something funny would be caused by the spring `JdbcTemplate` bean which was singleton and being thread safe will lock things when multiple workers will try to use it immediately. I changed it to be prototype but the problem staid the same. I even made it `new JdbcTemplate(singletonDatasource)` with no luck. On the other hand I thought it must not be JdbcTemplate as 99% of the Java world it is using it.

At this point I added the delay in the worker code as posted in my first **UPDATE** thinking it was important all workers receive the `PerformWork` notification. Once I did this all started working and no problems. However I would be interested to know what would have caused this.

Comment: How come your endPoints are processed as a stream?

Comment: There are not so many end points to make it worth using a parallel stream. Using a pre Java 8 for loop have no effect in the behavior. The issue stays the same. Please read my update. It was the work starting immediately that seems to be causing the issue.

Comment: Can you show me the Boss implementation?

Comment: the first two code extracts is pretty much it
`workers = ...`  is in the Boss constructor whereas `workers.values().forEach(` is in the onReceive part. I retained myself for publishing the full code because as you would expect in reality it is not as simple. The Boss onReceive deals with more than one type of messages that will start coming once the workers start doing stuff but in my case the problem was that the loop telling the workers to start processing never completed. Why? No idea and this is what this post is about.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but your fix, does not really make sense on it's own. There must be something wrong somewhere else. So to be more specific, could you post the WorkDone part of the Boss's onReceive function?